# How can I increase my disk space when Ubuntu is installed inside Windows?

Tags: 10.10, windows-7, disk

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed inside of Windows using [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer). I am running out of space on my Ubuntu disk (currently  405.1 MB free). I have a 180 GB hard drive and when I installed Ubuntu I only allocated 10 GB to it.

How can I resize my disk to give Ubuntu some more space?

Answer (score 2):

The official Wubi page lists 2 options:

- Using LVPM (but the site states that it wouldn't work with 10.04, so I guess it won't work with 10.10)
- Moving your /home to a new virtual disk using the `wubi-add-virtual-disk` script. You can install if from the [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?) page.

I would suggest using the second option. Note that it will move your `/home` to another virtual disk, if you were short on space in another folder you might have to move that folder instead of `/home`.

Comment: How will moving my `/home` directory to a virtual disk increase my space?

Comment: Well, when creating a new virtual disk, you are free to decide how much space you will allocate to it. This will thus increase your free space.

Comment: Did you try this? Or did you just reinstall Wubi with more space? Or better, make a proper dual boot? ;)